# Why the installation fails for this package? it says linux-headers not found but it is there

Tags: 12.04, drivers, apt, kernel, video

This package is failing to get installed, but the linux-headers are installed.

```
root@sun-Alienware-X51:/var/tmp# uname -a
Linux sun-Alienware-X51 3.5.0-28-generic #48~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 24 21:42:24 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@sun-Alienware-X51:/var/tmp# dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-28-generic              3.5.0-28.48~precise1                    Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-quantal           3.5.0.28.35                             Generic Linux kernel image


root@sun-Alienware-X51:/var/tmp# dpkg -i desktopvideo-9.6.9-amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package desktopvideo.
(Reading database ... 178666 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking desktopvideo (from desktopvideo-9.6.9-amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of desktopvideo:
 desktopvideo depends on linux-headers; however:
  Package linux-headers is not installed.
dpkg: error processing desktopvideo (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 desktopvideo

root@sun-Alienware-X51:/var/tmp# apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-28-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-3.5.0-28-generic is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 desktopvideo : Depends: linux-headers
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

root@sun-Alienware-X51:/var/tmp# dpkg -r desktopvideo 
(Reading database ... 178722 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing desktopvideo ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...

root@sun-Alienware-X51:/var/tmp# apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-28-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-3.5.0-28-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 134 not upgraded.
root@sun-Alienware-X51:/var/tmp#
```

**EDIT:**

```
root@sun-Alienware-X51:/var/tmp# sudo apt-get -f install linux-headers-3.5.0-28-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-3.5.0-28-generic is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.5.0-28-generic set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4 update-notifier-common libgphoto2-l10n
  libcdio-paranoia1 libgphoto2-port0 libsane-hpaio libraw5
  python-reportlab libgexiv2-1 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 python-renderpm acl
  libxrandr-ltsq2 apport-symptoms libieee1284-3
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic libsane-common linux-headers-3.5.0-23
  libexiv2-11 gksu libgksu2-0 libart-2.0-2 libcdio-cdda1 hplip-data
  libllvm3.1 python-reportlab-accel
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 141 not upgraded.
```

EDIT:

```
root@sun-Alienware-X51:/var/tmp# apt-get install linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4 update-notifier-common libgphoto2-l10n
  libcdio-paranoia1 libgphoto2-port0 libsane-hpaio libraw5
  python-reportlab libgexiv2-1 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 python-renderpm acl
  libxrandr-ltsq2 apport-symptoms libieee1284-3
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic libsane-common linux-headers-3.5.0-23
  libexiv2-11 gksu libgksu2-0 libart-2.0-2 libcdio-cdda1 hplip-data
  libllvm3.1 python-reportlab-accel
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-41 linux-headers-3.2.0-41-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-41 linux-headers-3.2.0-41-generic
  linux-headers-generic
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 141 not upgraded.
Need to get 12.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 67.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main linux-headers-3.2.0-41 all 3.2.0-41.66 [11.7 MB]
Get:2 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main linux-headers-3.2.0-41-generic amd64 3.2.0-41.66 [984 kB]
Get:3 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main linux-headers-generic amd64 3.2.0.41.49 [2,550 B]
Fetched 12.7 MB in 2s (6,138 kB/s)                 
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.2.0-41.
(Reading database ... 191914 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-headers-3.2.0-41 (from .../linux-headers-3.2.0-41_3.2.0-41.66_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.2.0-41-generic.
Unpacking linux-headers-3.2.0-41-generic (from .../linux-headers-3.2.0-41-generic_3.2.0-41.66_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-generic.
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (from .../linux-headers-generic_3.2.0.41.49_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-41 (3.2.0-41.66) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-41-generic (3.2.0-41.66) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-41-generic
Setting up linux-headers-generic (3.2.0.41.49) ...
root@sun-Alienware-X51:/var/tmp# dpkg -i desktopvideo-9.6.9-amd64.debSelecting previously unselected package desktopvideo.
(Reading database ... 213946 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking desktopvideo (from desktopvideo-9.6.9-amd64.deb) ...
Setting up desktopvideo (9.6.9) ...
* Creating settings directory
* Adding desktopvideo-9.6.9a9 to DKMS
* Building desktopvideo-9.6.9a9 for kernel version: 3.5.0-28-generic
* Installing desktopvideo-9.6.9a9
* Attempting to load driver
* Succesfully loaded new driver
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
root@sun-Alienware-X51:/var/tmp#
```

Comment: And what happens if you run `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Have you tried installing "linux-headers-generic" too?

Comment: @EricCarvalho: yes i did please see my EDIT. That still does not solve the issue. weired.

Comment: @brim4brim: after installing your suggested package it seems the package is installing but not sure - whats happening in background.